# $watch doesn't work and is driving me mad

Tags: angularjs, sockets, events

So, what I basically want to have is visualisation of the socket connection for the user. Meaning an indication wheter the client is connected to the server over socket.io or not.

Therefor I have service which keeps track of the socket state:

```
[...]
.factory('DataConnection', function(CONN_EVENTS, socket, $rootScope) {
    var dataConnection = {};

    dataConnection.states={
        // indicates if the user can interact with the ui
        uiEnabled: false,
        [...]
    };
    // socket IO connection states
    $rootScope.$on(CONN_EVENTS.socketAuth, function() {
        dataConnection.states.uiEnabled = true;
    });
    $rootScope.$on(CONN_EVENTS.socketUnAuth, function() {
        dataConnection.states.uiEnabled = false;
    });
    $rootScope.$on(CONN_EVENTS.socketConnLost, function() {
        dataConnection.states.uiEnabled = false;
    });
}
```

which sets the states based on events. This events are emitted in a different service/factory which handles the socket events.

I tried many approaches to sync these values with my controller. It kinda worked with a manual `$scope.$apply()`, but sometimes it gave me the `apply already in progress` error and since its very bad practice, I decided to not use it.

I ended up with this solution in my controller:

```
.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope, DataConnection) {
    $scope.$watch(function() {
        return DataConnection.states.uiEnabled
    }, function(uiEnabled) {
        $scope.uiEnabled = uiEnabled;
    }, true);
```

Which doesn't want to work somehow. When the socket get disconnected (the server gets shut down), the ui won't update. After interaction (e.g. trigger a popover), the ui will update as expected.
Is there anything I'm missing? Or something else I can try?

Comment: Why you are not using `.then()` to resolve `$watch` value instead of callback function

Comment: @ojuskulkarni I'm used to the callback approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research and this is my conclusion:
The $apply will trigger in three different cases ([Exploring Angular 1.3: Go fast with $applyAsync](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2015/01/14/exploring-angular-1.3-speed-up-with-applyAsync.html)) In my case (where I have to update the DOM after a socket event), the $apply has to be triggered manually.

This example is also found in the [Angular Wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-$scope.$apply()):

> If you're creating an AngularJS service (such as for sockets) it should have a $scope.$apply() anywhere it fires a callback.

I tried to trigger the $apply in the socket service already (instead of the controller), which worked way better and didn't give me the "$apply already in progress error".

Answer (score 1):

OK this is not a solution to get $watch working but instead just a workaround that "might" get your first approach using events to work without throwing a digest already in progress error. So instead of using $scope.$apply() enclose changes you make inside $timeout(function()) instead like this

```
$timeout(function(){
    // do whatever changes you want here
})  // no timeout value
```

**NOTE** that there is no timeout actually added above. Why i think this might work is because a $timeout automatically applies whatever changes you made once script inside completes execution (ie, its like a $scope.$spply() that won't throw a digest cycle already in progress error). I am not sure about this but just give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

I'd simply suggest you to use $scope.$applyAsync(), which means that if an apply in progress, it will do it on the next $digest only.

Answer (score 1):

To me is it OK your approach, to watch a function that returns an object to be observed, I don't know what could be the problem, but I would use callbacks:

```
.factory('DataConnection', function(CONN_EVENTS, socket, $rootScope) {
    var dataConnection = {};

    dataConnection.states={
        _uiEnabledBackingField: false,
        // indicates if the user can interact with the ui
        uiEnabled: function(val) {
            if (typeof val !== 'undefined') {
                 this._uiEnabledBackingField = val;
                 this.callback(val);
                 return;
            }
            return this._uiEnabledBackingField;
        },
        onUiEnabled: function(cb){ 
           if (cb) {
              this.callback = cb;
           }
        }
    };
});
```

And then in my controller:

```
.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope, DataConnection) {
    dataConnection.states.onUiEnabled(function(uiEnabled){
        $scope.uiEnabled = uiEnabled;
    });
});
```